# const_cast and const pointer to const vaiable

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, constants, const-cast

How is it possible that the value of `*p` and the value of `DIM` are different but the have the same address in memory?

```
const int DIM=9;
const int *p = &DIM;

* (int *) p = 18;     //like const_cast

cout<< &DIM <<"    "<< p << '\n';
cout << DIM << "   " << *p << '\n';
```

Answer (score 2):

You're changing the value of a `const` variable, which is **undefined behavior**.  Literally anything could happen when you do this, including your program crashing, your computer exploding, ...

If a variable is supposed to change, *don't make it const*.  The compiler is free to optimise away accesses to const variables, so even if you found a successful way to change the value in memory, your code might not even be accessing the original memory location.

Comment: Thanks you! I got it!
But i was testing const_cast limit, and is a little bit strange to see two different values in the same memory address

Answer (score 2):

It is a compiler optimization. Given that DIM is a constant, the compiler could have substituted its known value.

Comment: I just added this to my answer before you commented :-)  Upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

The code below does what you meant to do... as mentioned in other posts, if you mean to change the value of an variable, do not define it as `const`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int d= 9;
    int *p_d=&d;

    *p_d=18;

    printf("d=%d\np_d=%d\n",d,*p_d);
    return 0;
}
```

This code prints

```
d=18
p_d=18
```

Comment: Yes, i knew.. I was testing how compiler interpret a const-cast when pointer and variable are defined const.. And i didn't understand how was possibile that the programma return two differenti values that may ne in the same address